# Не могу задеплоить Веб-сайт на Vercel

Tags: frontend, deploy

Никак не получается сделать deploy своего html [проекта](https://github.com/MStan123/Web-Interface/tree/main). Хотя вроде бы я прописал необходимые `vercel.json` и `package.json`, но все равно выводит ошибку

```
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: arn1::2fj29-1694347415771-1a9a2d0aaae6
```

Если Вы знакомы с Vercel и знаете, где ошибка, скажите что же не так.
`Vercel.json`:

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "Space.mp4",
      "use": "@now/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "fotka.PNG",
      "use": "@now/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "style.css",
      "use": "@now/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "chart.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "map.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "index.html",
      "use": "@now/static"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что не правильно прописан файл `vercel.json`. Надо было явно указать какие файлы следует учитывать, в данном случае все! Надо вместо "@now/node" написать "@now/static"
Поэтому файл будет выглядеть так:

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "Space.mp4",
      "use": "@now/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "fotka.PNG",
      "use": "@now/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "style.css",
      "use": "@now/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "chart.js",
      "use": "@now/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "map.js",
      "use": "@now/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "index.html",
      "use": "@now/static"
    }
  ]
}
```